# Bash shell Array manipulation

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting

I have a small script which reads lines from a text file and stores them in an array.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line 
do
    array+=("$line")
done < $1

for ((i=0; i < ${#array[*]}; i++))
do
    echo "${array[i]}"
done
```

Here're the lines from my text file, which are printed after I run the script:

```
This is line1 of file1 with 10 words.
This is line2 of file2 with 100 words.
This is line3 of file3 with 1000 words.
...
```

So far it's fine. From here, I am trying to use words in line and form a new statement set. The final output will be constructed in the following format:

```
Capture ThisFile info-count1
filenum file1
Position of line: line1; Count of words: 10
```

Is there a way I can iterate through each array element (line words) and do this?

Basically, from here when I have the lines in the array, I want to iterate through each line, pick up certain words in the line and create a new statement set.

.....
UPDATE:
.....

This is how I have done it finally:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    getthelines=($line)
    printf '\n'
    echo "Capture ThisFile info_count"
    echo "filenum ${getthelines[4]}"
    echo "Position of line: ${getthelines[2]}; Count of words: ${getthelines[6]}"
    printf '\n'
done < $1
```

Many Thanks.

> #### See also:
>
> - [Split string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/bash-split-string-into-array)
> - [Redirect output to a bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753366/redirect-output-to-a-bash-array)
> - [How to iterate over associative arrays in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112687/how-to-iterate-over-associative-array-in-bash)
> - [Iterate over bash arrays, substitute array name dynamically, is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637758/iterate-over-bash-arrays-substitute-array-name-dynamically-is-this-possible)

Comment: Hi - can you rephrase the problem? It's not at all clear.

Comment: Hi suspectus, I take lines from a text file into one array. All lines come into the array. From here, I want to iterate through each line, pick up certain words in the line and create a new statement set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No way.  I wrote this code just yesterday to iterate over an array.

```
line="This is line1 of file1 with 10 words."
words=($line)
for word in ${words[@]};
do 
    echo "Word: $word"
done
```

Output:

```
Word: This
Word: is
Word: line1
Word: of
Word: file1
Word: with
Word: 10
Word: words.
```

Comment: Hi Jessemon, I do not need code to read an array. Instead, I want to iterate through each line, pick up certain words in the line and create a new statement set.

Comment: Ha!  @Sunshine, I had to read your question again and now I understand it.  You want the line as an array.  This is not the exact formatting you want, but I think you can take it from here right!  :)

Comment: Your script gave me the pointer to work out what I was looking for. I've updated my question with the final script as well. Thanks @Jessemon. :)